# Optionally-uninitialized class: std::is_trivially_constructible seems incorrect for non-default constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization, type-traits

I feel like `std::is_trivially_constructible<T, Arg>` isn't telling me the truth. First, context:

I have a small-vector class, `VectorND<T, N>`. Default-constructing it default-constructs its members, so `VectorND<float, 2>{} == VectorND<float, 2>{float{}, float{}} == VectorND<float, 2>{0.f, 0.f}`. This is the desired behavior.

However, sometimes, for perf-critical code, I want to construct them uninitialized. My thought was that I could use a tag type like so:

```
struct uninitalized_t {};
static constexpr uninitalized_t uninitalized;
...
    VectorND(uninitalized_t) {}
...
VectorND<float, 2> x{uninitalized}; //< Tell x to be uninitialized.
```

I can get that to work. First, if I do

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class VectorND {
    std::array<T, 2> x;
public:
    VectorND() = default;
    T& operator[](std::size_t i) { return x[i]; }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oTvo33xEb

then the default constructor leaves the data uninitialized. Same with if it's `VectorND() {}`.

If I make it `VectorND() : x{} {}` then the data is zeroed, making it no longer trivially constructible, as expected. This is the desired default behavior.

But if I add `explicit VectorND(uninitalized_t) {}`, then `VectorND<float, 2> x{uninitialized}` does appear to be uninitialized: https://godbolt.org/z/j9KWhPT7n This is again what I want. But for some reason, `std::is_trivially_constructible_v<VectorND<float, 2>, uninitalized_t>` is `false`. Why? I've tried

```
VectorND() = default; // Or VectorND() {};
explicit VectorND(uninitalized_t) {}
```

and

```
VectorND() = default; // Or VectorND() {};
explicit VectorND(uninitalized_t) : VectorND() {}
```

I still get `std::is_trivially_constructible_v<VectorND<float, 2>, uninitalized_t> == false`. https://godbolt.org/z/3n1Mz9dWd

Why?

Comment: Normally, one makes zero initialization via `VectorND x = {};` it is called value initialization and is different from default uninitialized construction `VectorND x;`. Construction/assignment can be trivial only  when you set construction to `= default` or not declare it at all.

Comment: So even though `VectorND() {}` does not initialize the data, it's not trivial? (https://godbolt.org/z/ExoTdj34v agrees). If that's the case, then what's the difference between triviality and initializedness?

Comment: AFAIK triviality in the standard is just a set of criteria for the default constructor, destructor, and copy & move constructors/assignment operators. It doesn't really have to do with whether something is initialized -- just with whether these operations are entirely synthesized by the compiler (e.g. not user-defined anywhere, but may be `= default`ed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

This doesn't work because this isn't how trivial constructors are defined by the standard.

Trivial has nothing to do with initialization (or lack-thereof), it's just a set of requirements that the standard lays out to define a constructor as *being* trivial -- a state which enables better code gen by the compiler and optimizations by library authors.

### Long Answer

The state of being trivial, as far as the C++ standard is concerned, has nothing to do with *whether* members are initialized. A *byproduct* of being trivial is that you may get uninitialized data from an object undergoing trivial value initialization -- but that does not mean that uninitialized data is the definition of triviality.

Formally speaking, the standard just outlines criterias for very specific constructors to be considered trivial:

- Default constructors are defined by [class.default.ctor/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.default.ctor#3)

  > A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
  >
  > - its class has no virtual functions ([class.virtual]) and no virtual base classes ([class.mi]), and
  > - no non-static data member of its class has a default member initializer ([class.mem]), and
  > - all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
  > - for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default constructor.
  >
  > Otherwise, the default constructor is non-trivial.
- Copy/Move constructors are defined by [class.copy.ctor/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.ctor#11)

  > A copy/move constructor for class X is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
  >
  > - class X has no virtual functions ([class.virtual]) and no virtual base classes ([class.mi]), and
  > - the constructor selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is trivial, and
  > - for each non-static data member of X that is of class type (or array thereof), the constructor selected to copy/move that member is trivial;
  >
  > otherwise the copy/move constructor is non-trivial.

**Note:** There are also similar requirements for `operator=` and for the destructor

There are not, however, any actual definitions for a custom constructor that is not a copy, move, or default constructor to be trivial. This means that any custom constructor **cannot** be considered trivial.

This also effectively means that `std::is_trivially_constructible<T,Args...>::value` can only evaluate to `true` if it tests for the default constructor, copy constructor, or move constructor.

### Why does being Trivial matter?

The state of being "trivial" exists because it gives better optimization guarantees both to the compiler and to library authors. Trivial constructors for copy/moving amount to simple `mov` instructions to just copy around the data (as opposed to requiring any cleanup or rewiring that
an object's constructor may usually require).

Additionally, if a type satisfies enough trivial requirements, it may be "Trivially Copyable" -- which allows compilers and library authors to simply *copy* the data around with `std::memcpy` rather than requiring constructor calls. This can also be used to view a different object representation without violating strict aliasing.

Comment: It feels like "trivial" should mean "this c'tor performs no actions", so it makes me sad that `std::is_trivially_constructible<T,Args...>::value` doesn't answer that question. In terms of the behavior I want: a class that defaults to zero'd but can be told to construct as uninitialized, I figured out how to do that. If I want to ask about that, I guess I can do `template <typename T>
concept is_uninitializable = std::is_trivial_v<T> || std::is_constructible_v<T, uninitalized_t>;` and then figure out a generic way to construct one. https://godbolt.org/z/qPPvzoxjj

Comment: @Ben The real question is _"How can the compiler know that it does no action?"_ This isn't necessarily as easy as it seems. A constructor can be defined in a different translation unit than the declaration -- which means that a compiler parsing the header would have *no way of knowing* that it performs no initialization (since it can't see the definition). This also becomes more confusing if the constructor _body_ now does something, but does no initialization. Currently, all queryable properties of constructors can be determined from the _declaration_, not the definition.

Comment: Ah, that makes some sense. I hadn’t considered that a c’tor might do nothing yet not be in the header. I’d be OK with it requiring any definition to be in the header.